# Carrier AC Air Handler Model #FC4DNF060 Filter Access Panel

Tags: hvac, air-filter, carrier

[image: Carrier Air Handler Filter Access Panel]

I have a Carrier AC Air Handler Model #FC4DNF060.  The filter access panel is blocked as shown in the photo (at bottom of unit).  Has anyone had a similar situation or advice on how I might be able to access in order to change the filter?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is a filter there? Is there a return-air vent somewhere else in the house/office? The situation you show is common, but typically the filter has been relocated somewhere else in the return-air ductwork system.